# How to define UDP connection sessions more correctly?

Tags: algorithm, go, udp

Listening to messages from the udp socket, I would like to somehow determine where packets come from and scatter in sessions to get a more detailed report on the received data, I just did it forehead, looking for the current session and recording in its channel, I would like to know if more elegant methods? [full code](https://pastebin.com/2YL4V7DR)

```
    func serve(ctx context.Context, addr string, port int) <-chan Message {
type session struct {
    id           int
    conn         *net.UDPAddr
    len          int64
    countMessage int64
    expiration   int64
    buffer       chan []byte
    run          func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, in chan []byte, ip string)
}

var (
    out         = make(chan Message, 64)
    done        = make(chan error, 1)
    wg          sync.WaitGroup
    localAddres = &net.UDPAddr{IP: net.ParseIP(addr), Port: port}
    bufPool     = sync.Pool{New: func() interface{} { return make([]byte, bufferSize) }}
    sessions    []*session

    // TODO может будет не линейный поиск, пока посмотрим так
    getSession = func(addr *net.UDPAddr) (*session, bool) {
        for _, s := range sessions {
            if reflect.DeepEqual(s.conn, addr) {
                return s, true
            }
        }
        return nil, false
    }
    addSession = func(s *session) {
        fmt.Printf("Add new session %s:%d id: %d \n", s.conn.IP.String(), s.conn.Port, s.id)
        sessions = append(sessions, s)
    }
    removeSession = func(sess *session) {
        for i, s := range sessions {
            if s.id == sess.id {
                fmt.Printf("Remove session %s:%d id: %d \n", s.conn.IP.String(), s.conn.Port, s.id)
                sessions = sessions[:i+copy(sessions[i:], sessions[i+1:])]
            }
        }
    }
    gc = func() {
        for {
            <-time.After(time.Duration(3 * time.Second))
            for _, s := range sessions {
                if time.Now().UnixNano() > s.expiration && s.expiration > 0 {
                    removeSession(s)
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
go gc()
go func() {
    pc, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", localAddres)
    if err != nil {
        done <- err
    }
    defer pc.Close()
    go func() {
        for {
            buff := bufPool.Get().([]byte)
            size, addr, err := pc.ReadFromUDP(buff[0:])
            if err != nil {
                done <- err
                return
            }
            switch s, ok := getSession(addr); ok {
            case true:
                s.buffer <- buff[0:size]
                bufPool.Put(buff)
                s.expiration = time.Now().Add(time.Duration(time.Second * 10)).UnixNano()
                atomic.AddInt64(&s.countMessage, 1)
                atomic.AddInt64(&s.len, int64(size))
            case false:
                s := &session{
                    id:         rand.Int(),
                    conn:       addr,
                    expiration: time.Now().UnixNano(),
                    buffer:     make(chan []byte, 64),
                    run: func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, in chan []byte, ip string) {
                        for b := range in {
                            var m Message
                            err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
                            if err != nil {
                                log.Fatal(err)
                                continue
                            }
                            m.Device_ip = ip
                            out <- m
                        }
                    },
                }
                wg.Add(1)
                s.buffer <- buff[0:size]
                bufPool.Put(buff)
                atomic.AddInt64(&s.countMessage, 1)
                atomic.AddInt64(&s.len, int64(size))
                go s.run(&wg, s.buffer, s.conn.IP.String())
                addSession(s)
            }
        }
    }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        wg.Wait()
        log.Println("cancelled")
        err = ctx.Err()
    case err = <-done:
        panic(err)
    }
}()

return out
}
```

Comment: your code won't compile! your code is racy in gc(). given those errors are fixed i m fine with this code. elegance is not that important when the code is not functional. lets fix it at first.

Comment: @mh-cbon I edited the code and made a link to pastebin

Comment: Дмитрий, please include the code into the question itself. Links can rot, questions have to be self-supporting.

Comment: @Mast insert full code for function.